# Is there a macro facility for NetBeans commands?

Tags: netbeans

I have a very common workflow in NetBeans:

1. Shutdown a Tomcat server
2. Do a clean and build
3. Launch a J2EE application (and Tomcat) in DEBUG mode.

Theree are a number of variants to this I use, but basically I'd like to be able to click on one button and have all this done in sequence -- which also requires that the previous operation complete before the next operation is initiated.

The "record macro" facility doesn't seem to do this -- it seems to be specific to editor commands.

Answer (score 0):

In the Run Menu, there is Repeat option (Ctrl-F11), I guess that is close to what you want.